# async cannot recrusively activate a function with template

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20

The environment is visual studio 2022 v143, /std:c++20

The program runs fine while I change the parallel_quick_sort function to the no-template version, but with the template, the compiler will throw an error C1001. I have no idea why this happen, considering I have successively done this before while implementing accumulation.

```
template<typename T>
std::list<T> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<T> input) {
    //std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    if (input.size() < 2) {
        return input;
    }
    //move first element in the list to result list and take it as pivot value
    std::list<T> result;
    result.splice(result.begin(), input, input.begin());
    T pivot = *result.begin();

    //partition the input array
    auto divide_point = std::partition(input.begin(), input.end(), [&](T const& t) {return t < pivot; });

    //move lower part of the list to separate list so that we can make recursive call
    std::list<T> lower_list;
    lower_list.splice(lower_list.end(), input, input.begin(), divide_point);

    auto new_lower(parallel_quick_sort<T>(std::move(lower_list)));
    //apply async to recrusive
    std::future<std::list<T>> new_upper_future(std::async(std::launch::async|std::launch::deferred, &parallel_quick_sort, std::move(input)));

    result.splice(result.begin(), new_lower);
    result.splice(result.end(), new_upper_future.get());

    return result;
        
}
```

I have tried the version without template and it works fine

```
std::list<double> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<double> input) 
{
    //std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    if (input.size() < 2) {
        return input;
    }
    //move first element in the list to result list and take it as pivot value
    std::list<double> result;
    result.splice(result.begin(), input, input.begin());
    double pivot = *result.begin();

    //partition the input array
    auto divide_point = std::partition(input.begin(), input.end(), [&](double const& t) {return t < pivot; });

    //move lower part of the list to separate list so that we can make recursive call
    std::list<double> lower_list;
    lower_list.splice(lower_list.end(), input, input.begin(), divide_point);

    auto new_lower(parallel_quick_sort(std::move(lower_list)));

    std::future<std::list<double>> new_upper_future(std::async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, &parallel_quick_sort, std::move(input)));

    result.splice(result.begin(), new_lower);
    result.splice(result.end(), new_upper_future.get());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "the compiler will throw an error C1001"
is not really helping, can you show the error message?

Comment: i think the template version is missing `<T>` : replace `&parallel_quick_sort` by `&parallel_quick_sort<T>`

Comment: Thank you for your response and for taking the time to help me. The C1001 error specifically reads as 'fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR (Parallism D:\Github-storage\StudyNotes\c++\Parallism\Parallel_quick_sort.h 74)'.

I believe that the template<T> should be able to be automatically deduced. I just tried it again, and the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Next, what line does it throw this error on?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem after updating the visual studio.
The code runs fine under new environment without changing any part of it.

But its really weird that in the following coding, whether the error that thread is passed by value or accidentally type `.` instead of `;` also triggered a C1001 error.